How to set the values for Permissions-Policy for custom Force.com site

How to set the values or enable Permissions-Policy for custom Force.com site ?

We have one custom page build on force.com platform, upon doing the penetration testing we are getting below result
Permissions-Policy : Doesn't exist.
How do we set/get the value via code or is there any configurable setting to get the Permissions-Policy ?


We also need to remove below two values form
X-Powered By  and  Server from response header ,how to achieve that??


Thanks for your time and help.
